# <link> tag does not import the .css

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp

I'm having some issue with importing a .css file in my jsp within the eclipse using this tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text.css">
```

The structure of my pages is so

```
WEB-INF
  >jsp
    >css(folder)
      >style.css
    >home.jsp
```

So basically home.jsp and the css folder are parallels, a relative url like the one i'm using should be fine according to most tutorial.

Do you see some problem?

Thank you

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Are you using a particular framework like spring?

Comment: All relative URLs in the HTML document are relative to the request URL as appears in your browser address bar. They are not relative to the disk file system structure in your server. So perhaps you are not opening the JSP by http://localhost:8080/contextname/home.jsp, but by something entirely different, apparently with an extra path.

Comment: @BalusC thx, i'm just letting the project run from eclipse, Stripes applies the preaction pattern, so the request goes always to the ActionBean rather then the jsp, but i though that it has nothing to do with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Change it to a slash.

Comment: done, still not working, i've read that closing link tag isnt a must though

Comment: Have you tried an absolute URL?  Like href="http://domain.com/full/path/style.css"?

Answer (score 1):

In your structure the css folder is `style` and in your link it is `css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css">
```